# Mostrar datos en input text segun lo seleccionado de un dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

tengo otro problema aqui compañeros.

Tengo el siguiente codigo el cual muestro unos datos de una api en un dropdown, hasta ahi todo bien. Lo que quiero es que cuando se seleccione un item de ese dropdown osea el nombre de un usuario me llene los campo de abajo que es nombre paellidos paterno y materno, telefono y correo.

Mi dropdown:

```html
<label>Usuario</label>
<p-dropdown [options]="SelectUsuarios" [(ngModel)]="id_usuario" optionLabel="nombre" placeholder="Seleccione usuario" optionValue="id_usuario">
<ng-template let-user pTemplate="item">
    <div class="flex align-items-center">
         <span>{{user.apellido_paterno}} {{user.apellido_materno}} / {{user.nombre}}</span>
    </div>
</ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

y los input son nombre, apellido paterno y materno, telefono y correo:

```
<div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
                    <label class="font-bold">Nombre(s)</label>
                    <input type="text" disabled pInputText [(ngModel)]="nombre"/>
                </div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué estas usando en el backend?

Comment: springboot amigo, de hecho por ahora en el back end hay personal y yo estoy del lado del front. hasta donde pude conecte la api a mi select osea muestro datos de una api ahi, el detalle es como seleccionar un dato y q segun ese dato me muestre la informacion escogida en el item, intente con un suscribe y onchange en el dropdaow pero en la api no mando a pedir especificamente por id si no en general

Comment: No he usado Spring Boot, suerte, pero usando .net y JavaScript creo un Ajax que ejecuta una función en el backend, donde envió el id y la función va a la DB y se trae la data correspondiente a ese id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear un método y luego llamarlo en el evento change del dropdown:

```
nombre:string;
apellido:string;
telefono:string;
correo:string

setUserData(user)
{
 this.nombre = user.nombre;
 this.apellido = user.apellido;
 this.telefono = user.telefono;
 this.correo = user.correo;
}
```